# Computing values before calling base constructor

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Is there any way in which you can call super constructor at the end of descendant class constructor?

It works in Java, but in C# the keyword `base` doesn't seem to be equivalent to Java's super.

Example:

```
class CommonChest : BasicKeyChest
{
    public CommonChest()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int key = rnd.Next(1, 6);
        int coins = rnd.Next(70, 121);
        super(key, coins, "Common");
    }
}
```

Comment: no, you can´t delay the execution of the constructor. This is design to avoid forgetting to call it and to ensure that all inherited members are initialized appropriately.

Comment: "It works in Java" No, it doesn't. Java requires it to be the first statement, so it's basically the same as C#'s `base()` It's just written in a different place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to postpone the call to the base constructor, it must complete before the derived constructor starts.

However, you can perform computations outside the derived constructor prior to calling the base constructor by providing an expression that you pass to the base:

```
class CommonChest : BasicKeyChest {
    public CommonChest()
    :   this(GenTuple()) {
    }
    private CommonChest(Tuple<int,int> keysCoins)
    :   base(keysCoins.Item1, keysCoins.Item2, "Common") {
    }
    private static Tuple<int,int> GenTuple() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int keys = rnd.Next(1, 6);
        int coins = rnd.Next(70, 121);
        return Tuple.Create(keys, coins);
    }
}
```

The above is a little tricky: a private constructor that takes a pair of ints is used to forward these ints to the base constructor. The tuple is generated inside `GenTuple` method, which is invoked *before* calling the `base` constructor.

Comment: @Rahul That's true. I hope that C# 7 will make the tuple ugliness less apparent, then the above fragment would have a chance at gaining some readability.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated way that could be solved if it was possible to call constructor at the end. But thanks this should be easiest way to solve this in C#.

Answer (score 5):

NO, the concept of using `base` keyword or `Constructor Initializer` is that the base constructor gets called first and then child constructor. So that all common or shared parameters across the childs gets initialized first and then specific properties of child classes. That's also one of the reason why an `abstract` class can have Constructor

Comment: Well that sucks... :) so i do need to break that code in 2 methods then?

Answer (score 3):

You could call a **static** method within the call to the base constructor:

```
class CommonChest : BasicKeyChest
{
    public CommonChest() : base(DoSomething())
    {

    }

    private static Tuple<int,int> DoSomething()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int key = rnd.Next(1, 6);
        int coins = rnd.Next(70, 121);
        return Tuple.Create(key, coins);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This design avoids that you access a member from the base-class within your derived constructor although it has not been yet initialized as it´s base-class constructor wasn´t called.

Imagine this was possible:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    {
        var a = base.MyBaseProperty;
        base();
    }
}
```

What will `a` be before the call to `base()`? As `myBaseProperty` is declared in the base-class it would be unitialized if the base-class constructor wasn´t the very first statement.

Furthermore the compiler will inform you if you forgot about the call to `base(...)` so that you can´t accidentally run your constructor without calling the base-class´ one.

Comment: That's don't prove anything, they could just forbid access instance fields before base call, only local variables and statice. It's just Java design flaw. Sad that it hasn't been fixed even in 2020