# How to avoid redundant computation in constructors

Tags: c#, constructor

I've got a constructor like so:

```
C(T x) : base(f(x))
{
   ...
   do something with f(x)
   ...
}
```

`f(x)` is not exposed as a member in the base class. How do I avoid calculating `f(x)` twice if I can't modify `C`s base?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "f(x) is not exposed as a member in the base class" ?

Comment: I mean there's no member of base that has the value `f(x)` which I can access directly. @DavidG has nailed it anyway I'm accepting his answer once the timer expires.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing values before calling base constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694927/computing-values-before-calling-base-constructor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two constructors, for example:

```
private C(WhateverFReturns x) : base(x)
{
    //do something with x
}

public C(T x) : this(f(x))
{

}
```

Comment: Good thinking!!